# Ajax Javascript doesn't change my CSS without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am changing my CSS styling using JavaScript code but it doesn't work when my search filter finds that element; the style effect doesn't change until I refresh the page.
Here is my code, it works perfectly when I refresh the page, but doesn't work dynamically without reloading the page.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $( ".card-auto-label:contains('Ny')" ).css( "background", "#5dd018" );
  $( ".card-auto-label:contains('Solgt')" ).css( "background", "red" );
  $( ".card__label:contains('Ny')" ).css( "background", "#5dd018" , "!important");
});
```

Comment: here is the page link https://www.tonderbilcentrum.dk/billager/ see when it loads the colors are there red and green but when i use search filter the colors didnot came with it then

Comment: As far as I can tell you only make changes to CSS on page load. You have to reapply this once the data is loaded from AJAX. You would have to show more of your code to give you a specific solution.

Comment: @daddygames actually i m applying only this code of class contains the text "ny" and "solgt" so bg color for "ny" is green and red for "solgt" but when i user search filters and it didnot reload the page.. then its not working.. and colors not showing.. and this is the simple code i already put in question

Comment: Have you tried something like this? `$("selector").css({"background-color": "5dd018"});`

Comment: @Damon but there is condition on specific wording which is contains

Comment: @Damon the color is working perfectly on my code.. but when i refresh the page. its not working dynamically without refreshing the page like searching using filters

Answer (score 1):

Your code only runs once, and it does not add CSS to the page globally, it adds it to the exact elements specified that already exist on the page.

Unlike using a `<style>` tag or a css file, applying styles with the jQuery css() function adds them on to the specific elements you target as inline css.

For example, `$(".someclass").css("mystyles")`

Has a result that looks like this: `<div class="someclass" style="mystyle"></div>`

This isn't the same as a css style globally in your page that looks like this:

`.someclass{ mystyle }`

In the first example, your style is applied ONLY to the element that you assigned it to with jQuery. If you add another element to the page with the exact same class and attributes, it will not inherit the style. There is nothing in the page telling it to be styled that way.

In the second example, the style is globally applied to every element with class `someclass`. It doesn't matter when the element is added to the page, onload or dynamically created later, the browser will apply it to any instance of `someclass` that it seems in the DOM.

Since you are relying on a jQuery function to determine where to put the styles, and that function cannot be replicated with css alone, I can see why the second example won't work for you. So to fix this issue, you need to have a function that triggers when your AJAX call finishes loading. I assume you are already doing something with the data from the AJAX call to add it to your page? Add the javascript code inside that function AFTER the content is added to the page and they will be updated with the styles. The way you have it written now, it is just firing once on page load.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided it seems that you are only applying the styling when you load the page. If you then later add more elements you want to style to the page they will not have the styling applied.

This is because when you write

```js
$( ".card-auto-label:contains('Ny')" ).css( "background", "#5dd018" );
```

it writes the style into the elements HTML style property like so

```
<div style="background: #5dd018">Ny</div>
```

making it only apply to that element. That's also why it works when you reload the page, because now the elements are on the page when your code runs, and the styling gets applied.

You need to put your code in a function

```js
function applyStyling() {
  $( ".card-auto-label:contains('Ny')" ).css( "background", "#5dd018" );
  $( ".card-auto-label:contains('Solgt')" ).css( "background", "red" );
  $( ".card__label:contains('Ny')" ).css( "background", "#5dd018" , "!important");
}
```

and then call that function every time **after** you add new elements to the page.

A better solution would be to put the styles in a CSS class and then add that class to the HTML elements you want to add the styling to.

```css
.Solgt {
  background: red;
}

.Ny {
  background: #5dd018;
}
```

```js
function applyStyling() {
  $( ".card-auto-label:contains('Ny')" ).addClass('Ny');
  $( ".card-auto-label:contains('Solgt')" ).addClass('Solgt');
  $( ".card__label:contains('Ny')" ).addClass('Ny');
}
```

Comment: then where should i call that function

Comment: You should call the function after your ajax request is completed and you have added the new elements to the page.

Comment: the classes are added and and its adding also.. but same issue wheni filter the search with out load then the background is default again. until i reload the page